# php yalinqo - iterate through result

Tags: php, foreach, menu, yalinqo

I am having a table structure as below where item_id -> 1,2 are main menu items ... and item_id ->3,4 are subitems to 1 which can be determined by the parent_id

[image]

And i am using the below code to fetch and iterate through this result. and to structure the menu correctly on the UI.

Until i am using the foreach loop 'foreach-1' everything works fine. and the result is

> 1-BAGS() ... 2-ACCESSORIES() ...

But when i add foreach loop 'foreach-2'. The result doesn't show (2-Accessories) as below

> 1-BAGS(3,4,) ...

And as you may see, i am using the yalinqo library to fetch the data from the result set. And there is very less help on yalinqo on www.

Is it that there some hidden curser thats creating a problem?
Or is there something wrong in the way the yalinqo query is formed?

If you have worked on yalinqo, please help me out here. Cause i am more of a .net user and have very less experience with php.

I am posting just the partial code here:

```
use \YaLinqo\Enumerable as E;

...

if ($connection)
    {
         $result = mysqli_query($connection, "CALL fetch_main_menu") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());

         $result_data =  E::from ($result) ;

         $top_menu = E::from ($result_data ) 
         ->where (function($item){return $item["parent_id"]==null;}) 
         ->select (function ($item){return $item;});

         //foreach - 1
         foreach ($top_menu as $i )
         {
             $item_id = $i["id"];
             $item_name = $i["name"];

             echo $item_id . '-' . $item_name ;

             //fetch subitems
             $sub_menu = E::from ($result_data) 
             ->where (function($item){global $item_id; return $item["parent_id"] != null && $item["parent_id"] == $item_id;})
             ->select (function ($item){return $item;});

             echo '(';

             //foreach - 2
             foreach($sub_menu as $sub_i)
             {
                 echo $sub_i["id"] . ',';
             }

             unset($sub_menu);

             echo ')  ... ';
         }
    }
```

P.S.: i would be happy to use another more efficient work around if there is for the menu bar structuring.

Comment: You can use noSQL database for example mongoDB and save you tree in the database. Or use postgrySql for insert array to field parents. Or use graphdatabase. Or mysql great 5.7 and use format json. and more more and etc. but you can select one query all data and one interator foreach.

Answer (score 4):

If you have any issues with YaLinqo, please don't hesitate to ask me directly or create a support issue in [YaLinqo's issue tracker](https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo/issues).

Your code is more complex where it's unnecessary and not complex enough where necessary. :)

1. `select (function ($item){return $item;})` is unnecessary, it does nothing, just `where` is enough (the same applies to .NET LINQ if you're using functional syntax):

   ```
   $top_menu = E::from ($result_data) 
       ->where (function($item){return $item["parent_id"]==null;});
   ```
2. Instead of using `global` you can add `use` statement to your anonymous functions:

   ```
   $sub_menu = E::from ($result_data) 
       ->where (function($item) use($item_id) {
           return $item["parent_id"] != null && $item["parent_id"] == $item_id;
       });
   ```

   Unlike .NET, variables need to be captured explicitly. Also, `global` should be avoided in new code.
3. Your model suggests using recursive functions, but your code supports only 2 levels. If you need just two levels, it's easy to do with a single query.

Let's assume we already have an array:

```
$items = [
    [ 'id' => 1, 'name' => "BAGS", 'parent_id' => null ],
    [ 'id' => 2, 'name' => "ACCESSORIES", 'parent_id' => null ],
    [ 'id' => 3, 'name' => "Messenger", 'parent_id' => 1 ],
    [ 'id' => 4, 'name' => "Sling", 'parent_id' => 1 ],
    [ 'id' => 5, 'name' => "Earrings", 'parent_id' => 2 ],
    [ 'id' => 6, 'name' => "Clip", 'parent_id' => 2 ],
];
```

Constructing menu hierarchy can be done this way:

```
$menu = from($items)
    ->where(function ($ti) {
        return $ti['parent_id'] === null;
    })
    ->select(function ($ti) use ($items) {
        return [
            'menu' => $ti,
            'items' => from($items)
                ->where(function ($si) use ($ti) {
                    return $si['parent_id'] === $ti['id'];
                })
        ];
    });

print_r($menu->toArrayDeep());
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [menu] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => BAGS
                    [parent_id] => 
                )
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Messenger
                            [parent_id] => 1
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [name] => Sling
                            [parent_id] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [menu] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => ACCESSORIES
                    [parent_id] => 
                )
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [name] => Earrings
                            [parent_id] => 2
                        )
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [name] => Clip
                            [parent_id] => 2
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Or, if all you need is a string:

```
$menustring = from($items)
    ->where(function ($ti) {
        return $ti['parent_id'] === null;
    })
    ->select(function ($ti) use ($items) {
        return "{$ti['id']}-{$ti['name']}("
        . from($items)
            ->where(function ($si) use ($ti) {
                return $si['parent_id'] === $ti['id'];
            })
            ->toString(',', function ($si) {
                return "{$si['id']}-{$si['name']}";
            })
        . ")";
    })
    ->toString(';');

echo($menustring);
```

Output:

```
1-BAGS(3-Messenger,4-Sling);2-ACCESSORIES(5-Earrings,6-Clip)
```

And finally, a recursive function which works with any level of nesting:

```
function get_menu_with_subitems ($items, $item)
{
    $subitems = from($items)
        ->where(function ($i) use ($item) {
            return $i['parent_id'] === $item['id'];
        })
        ->select(function ($i) use ($items) {
            return get_menu_with_subitems($items, $i);
        })
        ->toList();
    return [
        'id' => $item['id'],
        'name' => $item['name'],
        'items' => count($subitems) > 0 ? $subitems : null,
    ];
}

$root = [ 'id' => null, 'name' => 'Root' ];
$menu = get_menu_with_subitems($items, $root)['items'];
print_r($menu);
```

Output:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => BAGS
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Messenger
                            [items] => 
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [name] => Sling
                            [items] => 
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => ACCESSORIES
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [name] => Earrings
                            [items] => 
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [name] => Clip
                            [items] => 
                        )
                )
        )
)
```